# Phonemic & Syllabic N-Gram Distributions of the World's Languages

Tags: data-request, language

I am interested in doing some typological analyses by measuring the redundancy and IE entropy across languages in the phonemic and syllabic domains.  I've searched for quite a bit but could not find well documented frequencies of phonemes and syllables (preferably using IPA) across major world languages.

A tool to convert text corpus to phonetic and syllabic transcriptions would also be useful!

Comment: Does [this](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/527/1511) or [this](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3764/1511) help?

Comment: "A tool to convert text corpus to phonetic and syllabic transcriptions would also be useful!" -> ask as a separate question.

Comment: @seldamat, take a look at https://www.sttmedia.com/syllablefrequencies (unfortunately, rather 2-grams and 3-grams than syllables)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Stanislav's [comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/phonemic-syllabic-n-gram-distributions-of-the-worlds-languages#comment15336_5126):

**https://www.sttmedia.com/syllablefrequencies**

> With the Syllable Counter integrated in the WordCreator, it is possible to create frequency tables for syllables used in different texts.
>
> The Syllable Counter can be used for arbitrary symbol systems, alphabets and Unicode-texts.
>
> **For some languages, we have created frequency profiles for two-party syllables (digrams) and three-party syllables (trigrams)** on the basis of texts in the corresponding languages with at least 1.5 million characters.
>
> The texts consists of different literature genres to provide the best results.
>
> You can find the lists in the menu under "Syllable Lists".